# How to get author ID on post.php? $authordata returns NULL (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin, wordpress-action

I tried the code below on functions.php

```
function some_func($post_ID) {
    global $authordata;
    if( !is_null($authordata) ) {
        wp_set_object_terms($post_ID,2,'item_cat'); // I want to get this result.
    } else {    
        wp_set_object_terms($post_ID,7,'item_cat'); // $authordata seems to return NULL, and I get this result.
    }
}
add_action('publish_my_post_type','some_func');
```

Eventually, I want to get a author ID(NOT current user ID for some reason) of editing page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are inside a template like single.php
The $authordate is accessible inside the loop, so you may have forgotten to use

```
if (have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()):
        the_post();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation and link to official documentation to your answer such that others can learn from it (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)